# React Native Expo - .reduce() lazy imports bundle configuration

Tags: javascript, reactjs, react-native, ecmascript-6

I am trying to refactor the following code

```
export const translationGetters = {
    spanish: () => require("./assets/languages/es/translations.json"),
    english: () => require("./assets/languages/en/translations.json"),
}
```

like this

```
const APP_LANGUAGES = [{ locale: "es", ... }, { locale: "en", ... }, ...];
export const translationGetters = APP_LANGUAGES.reduce(
  (o, { locale }) => ({
    ...o,
    [locale]: () => require(`./assets/languages/${locale}/translations.json`), // lazy
  }),
  {}
);
```

But this code is invalid with the default bundle configuration. Why? How can I solve this problem?

Thanks.

Comment: What do you mean by invalid? Do you get an error?

Comment: @derpirscher "Invalid call. Failed to build bundle."

Comment: This may be a bundler issue. What are you building & bundling with?

Comment: @MynockSpit an Expo app

Comment: For what it's worth, I'd consider your original code much better.

Answer (score 1):

Your `APP_LANGUAGES` needs to include the full name you want for `translationGetters` key as well.

```
const APP_LANGUAGES = [
    { locale: "es", lang: 'spanish' },
    { locale: "en", lang: 'english' }
];
export const translationGetters = APP_LANGUAGES.reduce(
  (o, { locale, lang }) => ({
    ...o,
    [lang]: () => require(`./assets/languages/${locale}/translations.json`), // lazy
  }),
  {}
);
```